# QML Signal for Orientation Change Complete

Tags: qt, qml

I am working on an ESRI AppStudio app (AppStudio 3.1, Qt 5.11) for iPad and need to do some resizing of a QML control when the orientation changes. I found this page which seems to describe the official way to do this: https://wiki.qt.io/QML_orientation_observer

```
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
Rectangle {
    property bool isPortrait: Screen.primaryOrientation === Qt.PortraitOrientation || Screen.primaryOrientation === Qt.InvertedPortraitOrientation
    onIsPortraitChanged: console.log("isPortrait", isPortrait)
}
```

However, I have found the statement on that page that the binding will be fired after the height and width changes are completed to be incorrect. What I saw when I implemented this is that onIsPortraitChanged does indeed fire when the orientation changes but it does so before the orientation change animation completes and before the width of the app is resized. Is there a way I can trigger my code after the width is finished changing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that I found but it will only work for devices where the app is full screen and there might be a cleaner way to do this.

```
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
Window {
    id: app
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onWidthChanged: {
            if(app.width === Screen.width || app.width === Screen.height) {
                //calculate new size
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have no problem getting new width with correct signal for `orientationchanged`

```
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
Window {
    id: app
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    Screen.orientationUpdateMask:  Qt.LandscapeOrientation | Qt.PortraitOrientation
    ...
    ...
    Connections{
        target: my_object
        Screen.onPrimaryOrientationChanged:{
            console.log("orinetation changed, width: " + width )
        }
    }

}
```